# Meteor Nested Routing Using BlazeLayout

Tags: javascript, meteor, frameworks, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to use flow-router to render templates within a template based on nested routes. Rereading that confused me so I'll give an example.

Main Container:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="headerRight">
      <a href="/createCourse"><span class="headerButton" id="teachButton">Teach</span></a>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container" style="padding: 50px;"> 

   {{> mainLayout}}

  </div>
</body>

<template name="mainLayout">
  <main>
    {{>Template.dynamic template=main}}
  </main>
</template>
```

Main Container JS:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {main: "base"});
  }
});

FlowRouter.route('/createCourse', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {main: "courseChooseCont"});
  }
});
```

Nested Routes:

```
<template name="courseChooseCont">
  <header>
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/createCourse/category">Category</a></li>
    <li><a href="/createCourse/availabilityCheck">Availability</a></li>
    <li><a href="/createCourse/simpleAvailability">Simple Availability</a></li>
  </ul>

  {{> courseLayout}}

  <div name="courseMain"></div>

  <div class="bottomBar">
    <div class="back">Back</div>
    <div class="next">Next</div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="courseLayout">
  <main>
    {{>Template.dynamic template=content}}
  </main>
</template>
```

Nested Routes JS:

```
var createCourse = FlowRouter.group({
  prefix: '/createCourse'
});

createCourse.route('/', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("courseLayout", {content: "base"});
  }
});

createCourse.route('/availabilityCheck', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("courseLayout", {content: "availabilityCheck"});
  }
});

createCourse.route('/simpleAvailability', {
  action: function() {
    BlazeLayout.render("courseLayout", {content: "simpleAvailability"});
  }
});
```

When I render the nested routes it seems to overwrite the "courseChooseCont" template that should be housing the nested template and is simply displaying the nested template inside the 'Main Container'.

I'm assuming I'm using BlazeLayout wrong but I can't seem to find a solution.